# get the value of another table

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, phpmyadmin

The first table is like this:-

```
LocalityID | LocalityName | StateID | LocalityChamp

 1         |     anyName  |    1    |  AnYOne
```

The second table is like this :-

```
StateID | StateName

  1     |   anyState
```

I want to return the values like this

```
1    anyName      anyState    AnYOne
```

in codeignitor

Comment: what's the big deal then ?

Comment: That is why we have [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), `SELECT what_you_want FROM table 1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.StateID = table2.StateId;`

Comment: How to make in codignitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that first table name is locality and second table name is state. Use the following query

```
SELECT Locality.LocalityID , Locality.LocalityName, State.StateName from locality 
inner join State on State.StateID=Locality.StateID
```

or use Active Records .

**Edit**

In your model create a function like this;

```
function getChamps() {
 $this->db->select('Locality.LocalityID , Locality.LocalityName, State.StateName');
 $this->db->from('Locality');
 $this->db->join('State', 'State.StateID = Locality.StateID');
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result_array();
}
```

In your controller

```
function index()
{
 $data['Champs']=$this->Model_name->getChamps();
 $this->load->view('path/to/view',$data);
}
```

Comment: is there no way to make it in codignitor ?

Comment: Active Records / Query Builder, Read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html